# Laravel route not defined to controller function

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I have just followed a tutorial where the only code I needed in web.php to call a controller function was:

```
Route::resource('/articles', 'ArticleController');
```

This works for all my functions that were already there when creating the project (edit, update, destroy,...)
Now I need to make a second update function (upvote). But when creating a new function in the controller and routing to it I get the following error:

> Route [articles.upvote] not defined. (View: D:\school\web-backend\Oplossingen\hackernews\resources\views\articles\index.blade.php)

How do I make the "a" tag go to the upvote function of the controller?
My code:

```
public function upvote(Request $request, $id)
{ /* ArticleController.php */
    $article = Article::find($id);
    $article->points += 1;
    $article->save();
    Session::flash('succes', 'Upvote was a succes');

    return redirect()->route('articles.index');
}

td> <!-- index.blade.php !-->
                           <a href="{{ route('articles.upvote', ['articles'=>$storedArticle->id]) }}" class="btn btn-default">upvote</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>downvote</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ route('articles.edit', ['articles'=>$storedArticle->id]) }}" class="btn btn-default">edit</a>
                        </td>


Route::get('/', function () { /*route\web.php */
return view('welcome');
```

});

Route::resource('/articles', 'ArticleController');

Comment: Note: the version of Laravel I'm using is v5.3.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to name your route if you want to use the `articles.upvote` syntax.

Your web.php file should look like this:

```
// Use 'GET' or 'POST' depending on how you have your view setup
Route::get('/articles/{article}/upvote', 'ArticleController@upvote')->name('articles.upvote');
Route::resource('/articles', 'ArticleController');
```

More information on routing can be found here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes

Comment: Using this route gets me the right url (http://localhost:8000/articles/6/upvote) but also gives me an error:  MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: Are you using `Route::get()` or `Route::post()` ? It looks like you are generating the upvote link on an <a> tag so you need to be making a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your upvote function in your route. 
so you have to create new route in your web.php like

```
Route::post('articles/{Article}/{article_id}/upvote','ArticleController@upvote')->name('upvote');
```